# PHP/MYSQL - showing newest distinct value from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, select, private-messaging

This is my mysql table structure:

```
msgid | senderid | sender | recipientid | recipient | title | message | date
```

I'm looking to present in inbox for my private messaging system as Facebook have done. That is, each conversation is output ONE TIME from the table irrespective of whether it is incoming or outgoing. For example:

```
My username is 'admin'.

USER   |   MESSAGE       |   DATE   |  DIRECTION
Dan    | Hello           |  1/2/10  | Incoming
Bob    | How are you Bob?|  30/1/10 | Outgoing
```

The problem is not repeating the username because of differing directions. For example:

```
USER   |   MESSAGE       |   DATE   |  DIRECTION
Dan    | Hello           |  1/2/10  | Incoming
Bob    | How are you Bob?|  30/1/10 | Outgoing
Bob    | Hi admin        |  30/1/10 | Incoming
```

So I need to make sure that the only message that shows is the newest communication irrespective of the direction (i.e., the newest message with another user, irrespective of whether that user is the 'sender' or 'recipient').

I'm using PHP/MYSQL for this website. I've tried thousands of ways to do this but I just can't figure it out. It might be that my database is incorrectly structured. I will be online for a few hours (and will continually check after that) so feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you've tried? Also am I correct in saying you looking for the newest message which a user has either sent or received?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the newest message that the user has either send or received. I have tried:
`SELECT i.correspondent, m.subject, i.msg
FROM (
SELECT sender AS correspondent, MAX(message) msg
FROM mesages
WHERE receiver='Daniel'
GROUP BY sender
UNION
SELECT receiver AS correspondent, MAX(message)
FROM mesages
WHERE sender='Daniel'
GROUP BY receiver )i,
messages m
WHERE i.msg=m.message;`

Comment: `(SELECT Receiver, Subject, Message ,'Sender' as 'type' FROM m WHERE Sender='Daniel' ORDER By message desc limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Sender, Subject, Message ,'Reciever' as 'type'  FROM m WHERE Receiver='Daniel'ORDER By message desc limit 1)`

Comment: Now I am thinking of something like this: `$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender = '$user'";
                    $outgoing = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE reciever = '$user'";
                    $incoming = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                    while($outgoing = mysql_fetch_array($outgoing) && $incoming = mysql_fetch_array($incoming)){ ` Then see which direction is newer? I don't know!

Comment: Excuse the blocks of text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have somewhat solved my own question with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
         (SELECT id, reciever, recieverid, message, datetime FROM messages WHERE sender = '$user')
       UNION
          (SELECT id, sender, senderid, message, datetime FROM messages WHERE reciever = '$user')
          ) as t
       ORDER BY datetime DESC
    ) as t2
GROUP BY reciever ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

It seems to do the trick, although I don't know which messages are incoming or outgoing. I'll know if it works properly when I have a chance to invite some actual users.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this should do what you need:

```
SELECT
IF(senderid = :userId,recipient,sender) AS USER,
message,
date,
IF(senderid = :userId,'Outgoing','Incoming') AS DIRECTION
FROM message 
WHERE senderid = :userId OR recipientid = :userId 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The USER and DIRECTION is determined based on whether this user is the sender or not.

If you are only interested in the latest message you can add a LIMIT to this query.

Comment: Thanks Jim! I'm have a little trouble with "Outgoing","Incoming", I get an undefined constant/unexpected error. Could you help me out?

Comment: Oh I see! There are no "Outgoing" or "Incoming" values in the database. That is determined by whether the user is the sender or recipient. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @user1912319 Yeah. You should replace :userId with the id of the user you are getting messages for.

Comment: I've never seen a query like this before. I have changed userId to the user's id but I'm still getting the same ` unexpected 'Outgoing'` error. I have a feeling it is because neither "Outgoing" nor "Incoming" are defined anywhere in my table.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using and the full error message?

Comment: `$query = "SELECT
                                IF(senderid = '$userid'',reciever,sender) AS USER,
                                message,
                                date,
                                IF(senderid = '$userid',"Outgoing","Incoming") AS DIRECTION,
                                FROM message
                                WHERE senderid = '$userid' OR recieverid = '$userid'
                                ORDER BY date DESC";` Ignore the changes in columns and the typos. They are all correct.

Comment: The error message is: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Outgoing' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\messages.php on line 16`

Comment: @user1912319 The string you posted is enclosed in `"` and the SQL has `"` inside it, which is causing PHP to try and find outgoing. Try replacing `"` around incoming and outgoing with `'`. I'll update the question.

Comment: That fixed the previous error. Now I'm getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '4','Outgoing','Incoming') AS DIRECTION, FROM me' at line 2` Note that '4' refers to the user's id. Sorry this must be getting frustrating!

Comment: It looks like there may be an extra `'` after the first user id. Not frustrating, I'm happy to help.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT
                                IF(senderid = '$userid',reciever,sender) AS USER,
                                messages,
                                date,
                                IF(senderid = '$userid','Outgoing','Incoming') AS DIRECTION,
                                FROM messages
                                WHERE senderid = '$userid' OR recieverid = '$userid'
                                ORDER BY date DESC";` Still gives me: `You have an error in your SQL syntax... near 'FROM messages WHERE senderid = '4' OR recieveri' at line 6`

Comment: @user1912319 Bah. Mistake in my code. There's a comma after DIRECTION which shouldn't be there. Will update the answer.

Comment: It's still showing all the messages :( Not to worry, thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1912319 If you only wish to see one add "LIMIT 1" to the end of the query.